# Error cannot find symbol variable UTF_8 android studio

Tags: java, android

Error cannot find symbol utf 8 android. I dont understant why this happen when i try to implement this code :

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mysql"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
       layout:1.1.3'
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
       core:3.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `HTTP` from `HTTP.UTF_8`

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("envelope",UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It will working. But can you explain me why i whould remove HTTP.UTF_8 ?

Comment: The HTTP class does not contain the value UTF_8.